# Kusto query to show summary by percent of totals

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to get summary of failures in percentages of totals, see my query below. It is good, but I want it to show me **Vendor1=0.5 and Vendor2=0.5** (50% failures), and not just **Vendor1=1** (one failure with 0), **Vendor2=2** (two failures of 0)

```
datatable (Vendor:string, failure:int)
    ["Vendor1",3,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2", 7,
    "Vendor1",0,
    "Vendor2", 1]
| where failure == 0    
| summarize Failures=count() by Vendor
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please check if next query solves your scenario:

```
datatable (Vendor:string, failure:int)
    ["Vendor1",3,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2", 7,
    "Vendor1",0,
    "Vendor2", 1]   
| summarize Failures=countif(failure == 0), Total=count() by Vendor
| extend Result=Failures*1.0/Total
```

Answer (score 6):

A slight variation of [@Alexander Sloutsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669017/5070879):

```
datatable (Vendor:string, failure:int)
    ["Vendor1",3,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2",0,
    "Vendor2", 7,
    "Vendor1",0,
    "Vendor2", 1]   
| summarize Result = 1.0*countif(failure==0)/count() by Vendor
```

**[Demo](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUBY2w1LyU%2FCKr4pKizLx0HYW0xMyc0qJUq8y8Ek1eLgUgiFaCKDFU0jHWgQhBRYyUdAyIEFEwRxUyxKrIMBbI5%2BWqUSguzc1NLMqsSlUISi0uzSlRsFUw1DPQSs4vzSvJTNOAOtDW1kBTHyymoamQVKkAMQgA3JJ4CdgAAAA%3D&timespan=P1D)**